# If $F$ is increasing and $\mu$ is the measure induce by $F$, does $\mu(A)=m(F(A))$ for all measurable set $A$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ increasing. Then $F$ induce a (unique) measure $\mu$ bu defining $$\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a).$$

I was wondering : If $A$ is a (Lebesgue) measurable set, does $\mu(A)=m(F(A))$ where $m$ is the Lesbegue measure ? This is obviously true if $A=[a,b]$ or $A=(a,b)$ or $A=(a,b]$ or $A=[a,b)$, but is it true when $A$ is Lebesgue measurable or if $A$ is an unspecified Borel set ?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly false if F has discontinuities (that is, the associated measure has atoms).
For instance consider $F(x) = 1$ if $x \geq 0$, $0$ otherwise (it is non-decreasing but this example can easily be modified to satisfy your assumptions). The associated measure is the Dirac measure at $0$.
However, $m(F(\{0\})) = m(\{1\}) = 0$.